# How to get notified when a user changes password or requests a password reset?

Tags: django

For a password change I am using `auth_views.password_change` and for the password reset `auth_views.password_reset`.

How can I be notified when a user successfully changes their password? I do not need to know old nor new password. Just that the event took place, and for which user.

Similarly, I would like to get notified when someone requested a password reset and also when they successfully completed the reset procedure.

Can i do the above with signals or some simple patching? Or do I need to write my own views to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a decorator:

```
def notify_admins(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # send email to admins
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then, just add wrap it around the appropriate views in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^password_change/done/$', notify_admins(auth_views.password_change_done)),
    (r'^password_reset/done/$', notify_admins(auth_views.password_reset_done)),
    (r'^reset/done/$', notify_admins(auth_views.password_reset_complete)),
    ...
)
```

Keep in mind that sending email directly from a view, or in this case a decorator, will tie up the request. Instead of sending the email there directly, it would be better to create a custom signal and a handler that will fire off a thread to actually send the email. Then, in the decorator, you simply send the signal.

Comment: Arent signals synchronous though? Unless the mail happens in an asynch  process, wouldn't it be the same thing?

Comment: Hence the "fire off a thread" bit. If you create a thread to send the email in the signal it in effect becomes asynchronous. The signal returns processing and the new thread happily goes about it's email sending process.

Comment: Ah missed that little bit. Just focused on signals

Answer (score 4):

You could write a custom `password_change_form` that you pass to `password_change`. This form would extend django's `PasswordChangeForm` overriding its save method to first notify you of the change and then call it's parent `PasswordChangeForm`s save method.

Docs on password_change view:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change

Docs on ChangeForm:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm

Code for PasswordChangeForm:
https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py

Answer (score 3):

Beginning in Django 1.9, you can define your define your own password validators. You could even simply re-define an existing one, if you like. When you do, add a method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import MinimumLengthValidator
class MyPasswordValidator(MinimumLengthValidator):

    def password_changed(self, password, user):
        # put your password changed logic here
```

Be sure to include your new class in your settings as follows:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'my_package.password_validators.MyPasswordValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 8,
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Now, each time a password is changed by the user, your class MyPasswordValidator will be notified. In my experience, this is the best way to do this because:

1. When using signals to capture these events, you will also capture events where the system re-encoded an existing password due to a change in hashing parameters, in most cases, you would not want to capture these events and there's no obvious way to prevent it with signals.
2. You could simple add a function-call in the save() method of all your password-handling forms, but this becomes difficult when you want to do the same with the built in admin change password form and will not help you if password changes are made programmatically outside of a form.

I will caution you to be aware that the password parameter in password_changed() is in fact the user's raw password. Take care when handling this and absolutely never store this anywhere unencrypted/unhashed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using the `auth_views.password_change` built in view, then it would be easy to notify yourself once they are redirected after a successful change:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change

`password_change(request[, template_name, post_change_redirect, password_change_form])`

If you set the post_change_redirect url to redirect to one of your own views, then you simply take whatever action you want in that view to send a notification (email, database updates, etc).

You could even, in your redirect view, just do your notification and then return `password_change_done(request[, template_name])`

Comment: this would work. However, a refresh on that URL would also trigger the action. Even loading that URL by hand would trigger it. I would rather avoid these rare, but potential ways to erroneously notify me of a password change.

Comment: I agree that it would trigger. My answer was mostly going for the part of your question about not having to really write your own complete view. This just piggybacks on existing ones. As suggested in the other answer, you would have to do it through the actual form submission handler.

Answer (score 1):

You could also capture the signal and check if the password has changed. Just keep in mind that this code will run every time a user changes.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def record_password_change(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    if user:
        new_password = user.password
        try:
            old_password = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk).password
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            old_password = None

        if new_password != old_password:
            # do what you need here
```

Comment: Also bear in mind that if your administrator changes the password hasher parameters, this signal handler will get called for every user the next time they log in. This is important if you intend to enforce password expiration policies using this signal handler.