# Access request from the forms.Form to get data from dB related to user

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-request

So basic task is: add the template name and text to the `choices` in the `ChoiceField` with `Selector` widget to the form using the data from dB linked to the authenticated User only. `Template` is a model linked to user as a `ForeignKey`.

I'd like to access the request data(user) via the Form class linked to the connected view as `django.views.generic.View` class.

I've checked similar questions here: 
[Curious about get_form_kwargs in FormView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605008/curious-about-get-form-kwargs-in-formview#18605865)

and here: [Sending request.user object to ModelForm from class based generic view in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806224/sending-request-user-object-to-modelform-from-class-based-generic-view-in-django?rq=1)

and here: [Django: Accessing request in forms.py clean function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064000/django-accessing-request-in-forms-py-clean-function)

However they don't touch base with non-`FormView` classes. And as it's fairly old solutions, I was curious if there's more likely approach to reach `request` from `forms.Form` class.

Here's my code:

views.py

```
class InformFill(View):
form_class = InformForm
temlate_name = 'distrib_db/inform_fill.html'

def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.temlate_name, context={'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('distrib_db:login')

def post(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            inform = Inform(flt_numbr=form.cleaned_data['flight_number'], date=form.cleaned_data['date'],
                            template=form.cleaned_data['text'], user=request.user)
            inform.save()
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            flt_numbr = form.cleaned_data['flight_number']
            try:
                emails, contacts = get_mail_cnt(date, flt_numbr)
                # inform = get_object_or_404(Inform, pk=request['pk'])
                paxdata = PaxData(inform=inform, emails=' '.join(emails), contacts=' '.join(contacts))
                paxdata.save()
                return redirect('/inform/{0}/'.format(inform.pk))
            # 'distrib_db:detail', context={'pk': inform.id}
            except Exception as e:
                return render(request, 'distrib_db/sample.html',
                              context={'date': date, 'flight_number': flt_numbr, 'error': e})

                # return render(request, 'distrib_db/sample.html', context={'date': date, 'flt_numbr': flt_numbr})

        return render(request, self.temlate_name, context={'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('distrib_db:login')
```

forms.py

```
class InformForm(forms.Form):
flight_number = forms.CharField(5, widget=forms.TextInput())
date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
template = forms.ChoiceField(choices=templates, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'select_box',
                                                                          'onchange': 'javascript:changer();'}))
text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'txt_box', 'class': 'latin',
                                                    'maxlength': "160", 'onchange': 'javascript:validateTextArea();'}))
```

Generally speaking i'd like to achieve smth like this:

```
`class InformForm(forms.Form):
    def get_template_choices(self):
        templates = self.request.user.template_set.all()
        choices = []
        for t in templates: 
            choices.append((t.text, t.name))
        return choices

    flight_number = forms.CharField(5, widget=forms.TextInput())
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':                                                    
                                                      'datepicker'}))
    template = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_template_choices(), 
                                         widget=forms.Select(attrs=
                                        {'id': 'select_box',

                                         'onchange': 'javascript:changer();'}))
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'txt_box', 
                                                    'class': 'latin',
                                                    'maxlength': "160", 
                              'onchange': 'javascript:validateTextArea();'}))`
```

I'd appreciate any approach, mb I lack knowledge and asking newbie questions, sorry about it.

I just wanna get the `python-way` solution rather then build some `js/jinja` walk-arounds.

Thank you for your time!

#

After @Danielius comments, I've made some adjustments:

```
`class InformForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if user:
            self.fields['template'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(template.text, template.name) for template in user.template_set.all()]),
                                                        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'select_box', 'onchange': 'javascript:changer();'}))

    flight_number = forms.CharField(5, widget=forms.TextInput())
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
    # template = forms.ChoiceField(choices=templates, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'select_box',
    #                                                                           'onchange': 'javascript:changer();'}))
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'txt_box', 'class': 'latin',
                                                        'maxlength': "160", 'onchange': 'javascript:validateTextArea();'}))`
```

Got an error `AttributeError: 'InformForm' object has no attribute 'fields'`

Comment: what are you trying to do? can you explain a bit more

Comment: ok so what problem are you facing?

Comment: How can I access the request data from forms.Form class?

Comment: means the one that you are getting from the form after submission?

Comment: Nope, I need to pre-define the choices for the ChoiceField for template in my forms.py code sample using request data to link the templates that only that user has created.

Comment: pass `request` param to form via __init__ and set request as `self.request = request` variable. so now you can access request as self.request inside form methods.

Comment: tried that, there's an request variable undefined when I'm using it. Whatever self or w/o i'm using to access it from Class body, not the init method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass request to your form by changing your `__init__` method like this :

```
class InformForm(forms.Form):
...
   def __init__(self, user=None,*args, **kwargs):
        super(InformForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if user:  
            self.fields['somefield'] = forms.ChoiceField()                  
            self.fields['somefield'].widget = forms.Select()
            self.fields['somefield'].queryset = Someobject.objects.filter(User=user)
...
```

If the User is linked to other object in db by Foreign key, then you will get all the values of other object as select items.

Also , when creating form you could pass user like this :

```
form= InformForm(user=request.user,data=request.POST)
```

Comment: got an error:  
'InformForm' object has no attribute 'fields', are you sure that it works this way, or mb I'm not doing it right...

Comment: probably that's cos I'm using Form, not ModelForm for example, there's no fields pre-defined.

Comment: It's not because its not ModelForm, it was my mistake i forgot to add super method in __init__ before the clause, now i edited it ,check it ,maybe it will help

Comment: as I've edited the questions itself - you can find the code. I've added super, it throws no error, however, the field is not populated at all. I mean there's no such field. does it need to be saved or smth in order for it to stay?

Comment: I see , you commented your # template field, so yea, basicly we were just setting parameters for it, try now i edited it a bit - you should see the ChoiseField now, and the values should be okay

Comment: Hello Danielius, tried the way you told me, nothing appeared, so i removed the condition - it doesn't pass the parameter. Mb I should change smth in views.py?

Comment: Thanks Danielius, it was my mistake not o change def get(request) in views.py ;)