# Django: edit the choices set of forms.Select widget with dB data linked to current user in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Dear Python community,

Could you please share some insights with a newbie like myself regarding the following topic:

I would like to dynamically modify the inputs into form field input, specifically

`forms.ChoiceField(choices=((text, name), widget=forms.Select())`

As I was not able to access `request`from class in forms.py, I'd like to try editing the choices from `Django template engine`. Is it possible to edit the choices, taking the parameters from views.py method using jinja?

The question is conceptual, a few lines of code as an example would be enough, I'll pick it up.

The tricky part is - the data should be dependent on logged-in User's created model instances.

If there's no actual way to do it via python, but js only - please let me know so I don't dry to do the impossible.

Thank you!

Code sample for reference:

forms.py

```
class InformForm(forms.Form):

flight_number = forms.CharField(5, widget=forms.TextInput())
date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
template = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(template.text, template.name) for template in Template.objects.all()]),
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'select_box',
                                                        'onchange': 'javascript:changer();'}))
text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'txt_box', 'class': 'latin',
                                                    'maxlength': "160", 'onchange': 'javascript:validateTextArea();'}))
```

template

```html
<form class="form-signin form-container" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-element-wrapper">
            <div class="error-form-element">
                <span class="error-span">{{field.errors}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-label">{{field.label_tag}}</div>
            <div class="form-data">{{field}}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button id="cr_inf" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block stl-color"><span id="loader" class=""></span>Create inform</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
class InformFill(View):
form_class = InformForm
temlate_name = 'distrib_db/inform_fill.html'

def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.temlate_name, context={'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('distrib_db:login')

def post(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = self.form_class(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            inform = Inform(flt_numbr=form.cleaned_data['flight_number'], date=form.cleaned_data['date'],
                            template=form.cleaned_data['text'], request=request)
            inform.save()
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            flt_numbr = form.cleaned_data['flight_number']
            try:
                emails, contacts = get_mail_cnt(date, flt_numbr)
                # inform = get_object_or_404(Inform, pk=request['pk'])
                paxdata = PaxData(inform=inform, emails=' '.join(emails), contacts=' '.join(contacts))
                paxdata.save()
                return redirect('/inform/{0}/'.format(inform.pk))
            # 'distrib_db:detail', context={'pk': inform.id}
            except Exception as e:
                return render(request, 'distrib_db/sample.html',
                              context={'date': date, 'flight_number': flt_numbr, 'error': e})

                # return render(request, 'distrib_db/sample.html', context={'date': date, 'flt_numbr': flt_numbr})

        return render(request, self.temlate_name, context={'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('distrib_db:login')
```

QuerySet issue:

```
>>> usr = User.objects.filter(username='aleks')
```

> > > sample = tuple([(template.text, template.name) for template in usr.template_set.all()])
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'template_set'

Comment: There are multiple ways. So post your code of form initialization and form rendering.

Comment: @itzMEonTV, I've put the code to the q.

Comment: Post your views where you are rendering this form

Comment: @itzMEonTV,  done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `InformForm` class override `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(InformForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['template'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices="make choice based on user")
```

Comment: Tried that, ain't working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950895/access-request-from-the-forms-form-to-get-data-from-db-related-to-user

Comment: in `def get` you should `form = self.form_class(user=request.user)`

Comment: Tried that as well, it sends 'NoneType' to the form, therefore it can't bound to templates, doublechecked the query_set via manage.py shell, it works there.

Comment: can you update your question with latest change?both view and form

Comment: I fixed what was wrong, however I've got another issue, will u take a look? It's a queryset one. Doesn't return the needed value. Description updated.

Comment: That should be `usr = User.objects.get(username='aleks')`

Comment: Thank you for your help, m8, I figured out how it works ;)